# fopen() failed to open stream: HTTP request failed - Zabbix API

Tags: php, linux, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I have 2 servers: 1 LAMP web server where I have my webpages, and another server with Zabbix installed for monitoring things. My web server connects to the Zabbix server with a PHP script and uses the Zabbix API to read data and render graphs with Google Charts. I'm using this script to be exact: http://zabbixapi.confirm.ch/

The script was working great for a few months, and all of a sudden last week it became strange and started saying `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed`. The PHP Zabbix API script uses `fopen`, so I tried changing it to curl, but it still acted exactly the same. I noticed that the script can call the Zabbix API once to log in and get the authentication code, but then when it tries to make the 2nd API call to read the data, that's where it is hanging and gives me the error. If I add a `sleep(30)` in between the API calls, it works!

I installed a LAMP server on my local machine to test out the same script, and it works fast with no errors, and no sleep() line.

So I think something is limiting the rate that I can make the API calls (from the web server to the Zabbix server) and I cannot figure out what it is. Anybody have any ideas?

Btw, the PhpZabbixAPI library doesn't have an `fclose()` line. Will that affect anything?

Here's some sample outputs:

```
1st API request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"user.login","params":{"user":"username","password":"password"},"auth":"","id":"13969720350853"}

Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"cec4e961ddb7d193250d089f70d81e2e","id":"13969720350853"}

2nd API request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"history.get","params":{"output":"extend","itemids":["23713","23689","23707","23695"],"limit":96,"sortfield":"clock","sortorder":"DESC","history":0},"auth":"cec4e961ddb7d193250d089f70d81e2e","id":"13969720358004"}

Response: Could not connect to "http://<zabbixserver>/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php"
```

Also happens if I use file_get_contents too quickly in the CLI from the web server:

```
~# php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://<zabbix>/zabbix/index.php') or die(print_r(error_get_last(),true));"
1
~# php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://<zabbix>/zabbix/index.php') or die(print_r(error_get_last(),true));"
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => file_get_contents(http://<zabbix>/zabbix/index.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
    [file] => Command line code
    [line] => 1
)
```

Comment: Without knowing too much of what you have set-up, Adding sleep should only matter if the first response takes a while to return.

If the authentication takes "Too long" to return, the 2nd API call might fail(as it's not authenticated).

That's a pretty wild guess, but adding sleep() shouldn't matter at all at execution level.

Comment: The 1st API call returns the json response pretty fast. Its the 2nd call that hangs if I call it right after the 1st call. So if I make it wait 30 seconds before I make the 2nd call, it will work! Its really strange...

Comment: Is there anything else running between those two API calls? 

sleep() shouldn't really matter unless there's a race condition of some sort, This doesn't sound like the case though. 

What is 'pretty fast' btw for the first return? will sleep(2) work? or it has to be greater than 30?

Comment: The sleep(30) is not added to give time for the 1st api call to return a response. I added it so the 2nd call does not get called too fast because it will hang if it gets called right away.

Comment: It also happens when I use file_get_contents too quickly on the main index.php. I've added examples to the main post. file_get_contents returns 1 right away in the first call. If I run the same command instantly, it will hang and give me that error "failed to open stream".

Comment: Hmmm, does it work with a different URL? I'm basically guessing now just trying to help you troubleshoot. 

If it works fine with any other URL(of a different server), we can maybe pinpoint it further

Comment: Yep, I can keep on making calls one after another to google.com and it never hangs. Only my Zabbix server is hanging during the 2nd call from my web server. My calls to the Zabbix server does not hang when I run them from my localmachine's webserver.

Comment: You should look what your server is sending/receiving. If you can, install wireshark on the server (you can run it with X over ssh). But there exist also command line tools. Here I googled for you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764805/inspect-network-traffic-from-simple-linux-cli-app